# Symfony Logged in User has not all properties

Tags: symfony, authentication

I have extended the user model with some rights, so I can have rights for the user on different places to make some actions.

In the UserRepository I am getting all the stuff I need and I am storing everything in the user object:

```
if($user instanceof UserInterface){
                // get the roles
                $userRoles = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('BackofficeBundle:UserRoles')->findBy(
                    array('userId' => $user->getId())
                );

                if(!empty($userRoles)){
                    foreach ($userRoles as $userRole){
                        $user->setRoles($userRole->getRole());
                    }
                }

                // get the rights
                $userRights = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('BackofficeBundle:UserRights')->findBy(
                    array('userId' => $user->getId())
                );

                if(!empty($userRights)){
                    foreach ($userRights as $userRight){
                        $user->setRight($userRight->getActionRight());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Everything is fine and the userRights are setted properly. But when I am redirected to the /homepage route and get the user in the defaultController with:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

The $user object doesn't have anymore the rights. What is wrong here? Can I not't put extra things in the user object?

-- EDIT ---

I have also try to serialize the rights, so the user object can be saved in the session:

```
public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->rights
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->rights
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
```

In the symfony doku, they explain, that on every view they get the user every time from the DB. But how they manage the roles? The roles are every time there, even they are not in my user object, because the role nandling is done by another table.

Answer (score 0):

You should operate in the user Entity, in the getRoles method. The user Entity will be persisted in the session and then retrieved and refreshed from db.

In the repository you shouldn't edit your entities, but just retrieve them from db.

EDIT.
An hint: you should edit your model and add some relations `oneToMany` from `User` to `UserRoles` and to `UserRights` and then work on `getRoles` and `getRights` inside the User entity.

Comment: But when the User Entity is persisted in the Session, why I become whith $user = $this->getUser(); complete different object, as I have in UserRepository after I modify the user object and return it on login?

Comment: I have try to serialize the rights, but nothing happens: public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->rights
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->rights
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

Comment: you don't fetch the user from the repository unless you do that explicity. You shouldn't do that things in the repository: in the repository you should just select which entities to retrieve, without any edit.